# Nested Dictionaries to payload for the POST request Python

Tags: python, urllib

I am trying to make a Post request to an api using the below code:

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse

data = urllib.parse.urlencode({"value": [{"Start": {"Client_id": 111,"pipeline_name": "ABC","input_data": {"From": "", "To": "", "Date": "","CC": "", "Subject": "some text", "Body": ""}, "eml_file": ""}}]})
data = data.encode('utf-8', errors='ignore')
                   
with urllib.request.urlopen(GENERIC_PREDICTIVE_URL, data) as f:
    response = f.read().decode('utf-8', errors='ignore')
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<ipython-input-262-98ccec4e20b4>", line 1, in <module>
  with urllib.request.urlopen(GENERIC_PREDICTIVE_URL, data) as f:
 File "D:\ProgramFiles\lib\urllib\request.py", line 163, in urlopen
  return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
 File "D:\ProgramFiles\lib\urllib\request.py", line 472, in open
  response = meth(req, response)
 File "D:\ProgramFiles\lib\urllib\request.py", line 582, in http_response 
  'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
 File "D:\ProgramFiles\lib\urllib\request.py", line 510, in error
  return self._call_chain(*args)
 File "D:\ProgramFiles\lib\urllib\request.py", line 444, in _call_chain
  result = func(*args)
 File "D:\ProgramFiles\lib\urllib\request.py", line 590, in http_error_default
  raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
HTTPError: Unsupported Media Type
```

I believe this is because of the format of data but I don't understand how to encode it properly.

I tried the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43600125/nested-dictionaries-to-json-for-the-post-request-python/57999804), but couldn't resolve the issue.

Also, the api is giving response using postman.
Adding postman screenshots also here [Postman screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQyx7.png)

Comment: @SiHa In case the attached image is not clear, the error is : HTTPError: Unsupported Media Type

Comment: @NehaBhandari The image doesn't actually mention `Unsupported Media Type` and it seems as if not the whole error has been posted.

Comment: @MitchellvanZuylen : sorry i missed the last line while taking the snip.

Comment: Here is the error - Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-262-98ccec4e20b4>", line 1, in <module>
    with urllib.request.urlopen(GENERIC_PREDICTIVE_URL, data) as f:

  File "D:\ProgramFiles\lib\urllib\request.py", line 163, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)

  File "D:\ProgramFiles\lib\urllib\request.py", line 472, in open
    response = meth(req, response)

Comment: File "D:\ProgramFiles\lib\urllib\request.py", line 582, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)

  File "D:\ProgramFiles\lib\urllib\request.py", line 510, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)

  File "D:\ProgramFiles\lib\urllib\request.py", line 444, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)

  File "D:\ProgramFiles\lib\urllib\request.py", line 590, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)

HTTPError: Unsupported Media Type

Comment: You are URL-encoding the data of the request; this is only necessary if you are going to pass this data in the URL itself (e.g. as a query argument).  Are you sure the API in question requires that, or does it just accept JSON?  In that case you should be able to call `urllib.request.urlopen(url, data=json.dumps(your_dict))`

Comment: @NehaBhandari You can edit your question after posting.  ~Please edit your question and paste the error traceback there, not in comments.~ No worries, I went ahead and did it.

Comment: @Iguananaut Thanks for your response. I need to pass the data in url itself. i tried this way urllib.request.urlopen(url, data=json.dumps(your_dict)) , but getting error: TypeError: POST data should be bytes or an iterable of bytes. It cannot be of type str.

Comment: Add `.encode('utf-8')` after `json.dumps()`. It would be unusual for a POST method to take data in the URL itself.

Comment: @Iguananaut i tried this way urllib.request.urlopen(GENERIC_PREDICTIVE_URL, data=json.dumps(your_dict).encode('utf-8')) , again getting the error : HTTPError: Unsupported Media Type

Comment: Without knowing more about the API you're posting to and what it expects it's impossible to say. You might also have to pass a `Content-Type: application/json` header, for example. If indeed it even accepts JSON.

Comment: Also, when i try another api which has payload in the format {"a":"some text" ,"b:"some text"} the code i shared (in the issue description) works fine but if the payload is nested it giving the error - HTTPError: Unsupported Media Type

Comment: @Iguananaut let me know what details of the api you might require i will try to share it with you if possible

Comment: Well do you know for sure if it accepts JSON in the POST body?

Comment: Yes it it accepts JSON in POST body

Answer (score 0):

You can simply try this using python `requests` library:

```
data = {"value": [{"Start": {"Client_id": 111,"pipeline_name": "ABC","input_data": {"From": "", "To": "", "Date": "","CC": "", "Subject": "some text", "Body": ""}, "eml_file": ""}}]}
response = requests.post(url, data=data)
```

Comment: Maalik Watto : this also gives error <Response [415]>

{"detail":"Unsupported media type \"application/x-www-form-urlencoded\" in request."} . It works fine for another api which accepts data in format {"a":"some text","b":"some text"}