# Python POST request with Nested Dictionary values/args

Tags: python, python-requests, http-post

Already looked at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10768522/python-send-post-with-header), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43600125/nested-dictionaries-to-json-for-the-post-request-python) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15900338/python-request-post-with-param-data) but still having issues.
I have a `POST data` that looks like this:

```py
{
   "config":{
             "param1": "param1 value",
             "param2": "param2 value",
             "param3": "param3 value"
            },
   "name": "Testing API",
   "url": "https://testingapi.my.own.com",
   "enabled": true
}
```

I have the following headers:

```py
{
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  "referer": "https://testingapi.my.own.com",
  "X-CSRFToken": "my token value here"
}
```

How do format this for the `session.post`?

I am keep getting the response code of `400` and logs are stating that I am not sending the required params in the `post` request.

Here is the code:

```py
headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json",
           "referer": "https://testingapi.my.own.com",
           "X-CSRFToken": "my token"
}

request_data = {
   "config":{
             "param1": "param1 value",
             "param2": "param2 value",
             "param3": "param3 value"
            },
   "name": "Testing API",
   "url": "https://testingapi.my.own.com",
   "enabled": "true"
}

#tried the following:
r = session.post(url, data =  request_data, headers=headers)
r = session.post(url, json =  json.dumps(request_data), headers=headers)
```

Comment: Did you tried the `response.text` or `response.json()` to see if the api response has any validation errors?

Comment: How are you `POST`ing the payload? `requests.post(url, data=...)` or `requests.post(url, json=...)`?

Comment: @PaulM. I tried both but no joy

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM The error is: `Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got a str.`

Comment: Is it possible for you to share what the actual API/endpoint is?

Comment: @PaulM. Unfortunately, it's behind corporate proxy

Comment: @Shery Try `session.post(url, json=request_data, ...)`

Comment: @PaulM.that's it ... it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `data = request_data` your nested dictionary is not packaged into the request body as you expect. Try inspecting the `body` attribute of the `request` object:

```
import requests
s = requests.Session()
request_data = {
    "config":{
        "param1": "param1 value",
        "param2": "param2 value",
        "param3": "param3 value"
     },
    "name": "Testing API",
    "url": "https://testingapi.my.own.com",
    "enabled": True
}
r = s.post('https://httpbin.org/post/404', data=request_data )
r.request.body
```

returns

> 'url=https%3A%2F%2Ftestingapi.my.own.com&enabled=True&config=param3&config=param2&config=param1&name=Testing+API'

And when you `json =  json.dumps(request_data)` you json-dump your data **twice**, so so the server (after unserializing the data one time) only sees a json string rather than an unserialized dict (see [requests docs](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests)).

So you need to either serialize your data before passing it to `data`

```
r = s.post('https://httpbin.org/post/404', data=json.dumps(request_data), )
```

or as Paul has suggested, use the `json` parameter and pass your data dict to it:

```
r = s.post('https://httpbin.org/post/404', json=request_data)
```