# Am I sending a this json data correctly using the python requests library?

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I'm trying to send this json array to an API using request.post():

```json
{
  "insert": [
    {
      "data": "48bPRVkgvHwjG2VUTkPLaGazynZ6RxETuNGsYZNBrtb7ZkAUqY1NE2iGqoLd8EFsvhbDGW8gNb96Jce8fg2aiY8A5mbd8zf",
      "tag": "0x1001"
    }
  ]
}
```

[I was told](https://github.com/z0rg0n/multiyat/issues/3) the json post has to be in an array by one of the devs at the site I'm posting to.
I also pored over these two examples in the API docs.[1(edit emojiId section)](https://api-docs.y.at/docs/api-ref#edit-emojiid),[2(adding an emoji id record)](https://api-docs.y.at/docs/integration_general)

What I tried so far is posting this dictionary:

```py
{'insert': [{'data': '48bPRVkgvHwjG2VUTkPLaGazynZ6RxETuNGsYZNBrtb7ZkAUqY1NE2iGqoLd8EFsvhbDGW8gNb96Jce8fg2aiY8A5mbd8zf', 'tag': '0x1001'}]}
```

Using both of these post requests:

```py
requests.post(base_url + '/emoji_id/', json=dict_data, headers=headers)
```

```py
requests.post(base_url + '/emoji_id/', data=dict_data, headers=headers)
```

I then converted the dictionary to a string using

```py
dict_data = json.dumps(dict_data, skipkeys=True, separators=(',', ':'))
```

and again sent it using both json and data.

Each returned a 405 error.

The next thing I tried is [using the example this stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57999804/18359845) to send a nested json. Here's my code for that attempt:

```py
params = [{'data':'48bPRVkgvHwjG2VUTkPLaGazynZ6RxETuNGsYZNBrtb7ZkAUqY1NE2iGqoLd8EFsvhbDGW8gNb96Jce8fg2aiY8A5mbd8zf','tag':'0x1001'}]
# Tried above both with [ ] on outside making it a list and without
payload = {'insert': json.dumps(params, skipkeys=True, separators=(',', ':'))}
requests.post(base_url + '/emoji_id/', json=payload, headers=headers)
```

Again, I used both **json=payload** and **data=payload** and again I tried it both as a dictionary and converting to a string using the same json.dumps method as above. Same as before each returned a 405 response.

My question is, am I using request.post() correctly in at least one of these attempts? If so, I must be missing something about what the API expects and can start down that rabbit hole.

Comment: What does the response body look like?

Comment: Welcome to SO.   Are you certain you're using the right method?   Which part of the api are you using?  From my brief look, the 'edit emoji' uses the ```patch``` method.

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark Each responce.content was:

b''

Which kind of reinforces that I'm just doing something wrong.
          
@ewong Ty! I'm pretty new to coding and entirely new to working with APIs and JSON. I didn't know there were different methods of sending these requests before just now. I've only used ```GET``` and ```POST``` so far. I'll do some research into ```post``` now. I bet that's what I'm missing. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

@ewong nailed it. I didn't realize I had to use the `patch` method instead of the `post` method.

So my issue was fixed using:

```py
requests.patch(base_url + '/emoji_id/', json=dict_data, headers=headers)
```

instead of request.post. The difference between the two still seems subtle to me at this point but the example given in the API docs clearly show a patch method being used and that's what worked.